# ORA-12541: TNS: No listener error when i change the datasource

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, oracle

I am changing the data source from the SQL server to Oracle.

There is a SQL Server (server1), Oracle Server (server2), Windows Service (Server3).

This windows service C#, do the job of picking the data from SQL table to a different table.
I deploy windows service in Server3.
For this in the code, I need to mention the oracle connection string instead of SQL which is in server3.

**SQL Server connection string:**

```
'Dim strConn As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=support.sdfdf.com; Initial Catalog=countssss; User ID=sdfsdf; Password=*****"
```

**Oracle connection string:**

```
Dim strConn As String = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.xxx.xx.xxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=BI_HRxxxx)));User Id=jp;Password=*asdasd**;"
            Dim conn As New OracleConnection(strConn)
```

The moment I changed the code, I am getting an error,

> ORA-12541: TNS: No listener

I know this is happening because ***tns listener service is not running.***

This tns listener service needs to be installed.

I have two questions:

1. Is oracle installation is mandatory or any other alternative without installation oracle?.
2. Is Entire Oracle installation(Full Package) is mandatory to deploy tns service in server3.
3. If yes where do I get the installation file.
4. If not, what is the package that will install the TNS service?
5. Is there any specific version that needs to install? means do I need to install the same version of the package for tns service in server3, which is the same version of the Oracle server running on Server2.

Comment: Did you not install Oracle Database on your Oracle server? That's where the listener runs - not on the client. If you're seeing that error then it sounds like you probably don't need any other software on server3. Have you created a database and started all the services on server2?

Comment: Yes, the Oracle server is running fine in server 2. Since I am consuming the oracle DB data from server3 which connects towards server2, do you mean I don't need any oracle listener in server2?

Comment: You need Oracle Listener on server2. It should have been installed at the same time / from the same package as the database. Perhaps the service just isn't started?

Comment: As others stated, the listener is a service that runs _on the database server_, not the client.  The very fact that you got an ORA-12541 means that the client did send a request to that server.  Therefore, we can be confident that you do not need any additional software on your client (server 3).  You need to either 1) insure that the listener service is started on your DB server, or 2) insure that you are specifying the correct database server (server 2) in the HOST= of your connection string.